# Keyboard not showing in api 19 but working fine in lollipop

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am running my application on two emulators api 23 and api 19. When I click on EditText in api 19 no soft keyboard displayed whereas its working correctly on api 23. There might be some problem in my layout file which is given below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

tools:context="com.technistan.ledger.NewLedger">


<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    ></include>
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_category"
            android:layout_width="232dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnR"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/icons"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layoutReveal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLedgerName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter Ledger Name"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCurrencySign"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter Current Type (e.g USD, $, PKR)"/>



</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Transaction (Optional)"/>


        <TextView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvShowDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sep-13-2015"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                >


                />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonCredit"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/radioButtonDebit"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />
            </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="13dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Credit"
            android:id="@+id/tvCredit"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:text="Debit"
            android:id="@+id/tvDebit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCredit"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>





    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/etAmount" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:lines="3"
        android:id="@+id/etDescription" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check it your manifest entry properly ?